# What exactly is Agent Jones doing in this scene?

Tags: the-matrix

[image]

You can see Agent Jones placing an arm in front of Agent Brown in the background. How come? I never understood why. Is it because he "cares" about his colleague's safety?

Comment: Or was he just reaching for the elevator button?

Comment: At 02:06:05 in the movie.

Comment: @Gallifreyan He doesn't seem to be reaching for the elevator button.

Comment: @Valorum Somewhere around that point. Have any idea as to what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script direction is a little vague as to what's going on in the background, simply noting that

> *...Then with one quick strike to the chest he sends Agent Smith flying backwards.*
> ***For the first time since their inception, the Agents know fear***
>
> <sub><sup>[Art of the Matrix - Complete Movie Script](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Art_of_The_Matrix)</sup></sub>

I'd assume the gesture was supposed to convey that fear in some fashion.

Comment: For the record, this part of the scene doesn't appear at all in the 1996 draft script, then turns up in the 1997 draft in a virtually identical format to the wording above.

Comment: Hmm. It's an interesting way of conveying it. My friend -- who is a major fan of slash -- thinks it was a "gay" moment (e.g., "daww, he is keeping Brown back 'cuz he has feeling for him), but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @Deutertraumen - I figured he's just rocked back on his feet and seeking to stabilise himself. Check out the guys *right at the start of this video*; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4L6vJHEVsJw

Comment: Stabilizing himself. When I look at it, Brown appears to be stepping forward, but stops after Smith gets kicked back by Neo. I don't know why my friend sees yaoi in there. You don't see it, do you?

Comment: @Deutertraumen - My first instinct when seeing it was that Jones was *restraining* Brown, preventing him from getting between Smith and Neo

Comment: I saw it more as a "No, wait, let's see how this plays out" act.  Brown was about to join the fight, but Jones thought it'd be better to analyze the situation and Neo's new abilities before jumping in so they can perhaps spot weaknesses.

Comment: @Valorum Right. The "why" seems to be the result of their fear, but still, Smith hadn't been blown up yet. He couldn't have been holding Brown back to protect him, since Agents cannot die, and they didn't run away until Smith exploded before their very eyes.

Comment: @starpilotsix Your explanation makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Furthermore, their hesitation distinguishes them from the reckless Smith - who is more "human" than his colleagues.

Comment: @Deutertraumen Smith hasn't died yet, true, however the very fact that Neo was able to *knock Smith on his ass* is already a thousand times beyond what any human should be able to do to an Agent.  It's cause enough for caution, which is why Jones is holding Brown back.  *Something is clearly wrong here, let's wait it out.*